# How to count aggregate function on Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have a calculate field (called TOTAL) on Tableau which is connected to R studio to create outputs through R (the R code is written inside the Calculate Field).

The R code has a function that returns a bunch of 100 and 50 in a function passing .arg's from Tableau, and the number of these will change if a given parameter changes.

This is the Calculate Field TOTAL content:

```
SCRIPT_STR("
    numbers <- function(a,b,c,parameter){
        a <- as.numeric(a)
        b <- as.numeric(b)
        c <- as.numeric(c)
        parameter <- as.numeric(parameter)
        al = ifelse(a > ((parameter * b) + b) | a < (c - (parameter * c)),'100','50')
        return(al)
    }
    numbers(.arg1,.arg2,.arg3,.arg4)
", SUM([A]),SUM([B]),SUM([C]),[PARAMETER])
```

Now, once I visualize the result (as example, in a Pie Chart), the chart doesn't tell how many 100's and how many 50's are, but it divides the number proportion through properly. Like this:

[image: TOTAL result in Pie Chart]
[image: TOTAL result in Pie Chart]

Obviously the 100 in the first picture means one 100 of all the 100's that the output has, but I'd like to know the total of 100's and 50's

I tried to use COUNT over the TOTAL field, but it launches an error describing that TOTAL is already an aggregate function and it cannot be aggregated.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is just a hunch but I think window_avg or a level of detail calculation might help because these will allow you to aggregate and aggregation. [link](https://community.tableau.com/thread/200670) [link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this process:

Create two calculated fields one for 100's and other for 50's

```
if Total = 100
then 1
else 0
end
```

For 50's count

```
if total=50
then 1
else 0
end
```

Now take the running sum for both the calculated fields and then place both formulas in tool tip.